# PHP glob/scandir and Linux softlinks/permissions

Tags: php, apache, permissions, symlink

I'm trying to write a simple online music player to improve my programming.

I have a server running CentOS 6.5, with an external hard disk containing all my files. I mounted my storage partition to `/mnt/storage` and my music is in `/mnt/storage/cascornelissen/Muziek`, which has the following permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 19 cascornelissen ftpusers       4096 Nov  4 14:43 Muziek
```

Then I have a simple httpd webserver, hosting the project in `/var/www/html/melodi`, which constains a softlink to the Muziek directory mentioned earlier:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root           ftpusers   34 Jan 26 22:31 music -> /mnt/storage/cascornelissen/Muziek
```

I want to use PHP's `glob` to list all the files but that returned an empty array. So I tried `scandir("music")` but it returns the following error:

```
Warning: scandir(music): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /var/www/html/melodi/index.php on line 42
```

Any ideas on how to fix this permissions issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
chmod ugo+x /mnt /mnt/storage /mnt/storage/cascornelissen
```

Probably some part of your path will not allow entry for your Apache user. Allowing entry to a directory means adding `x` or `execute permissions` to the directory.

**Explanation**

```
# create path a/b
mkdir -p a/b
ls a/b          # this works

# now remove all permissions for a
chmod 000 a
ls a/b          # ls: cannot access a/b: Permission denied
                # but why, we should still have permission for b??
                # Now, lets add x permission for a:
chmod ugo+x a
ls a/b          # works again
ls a            # ls: cannot open directory a: Permission denied
                # So, we cannot list contents of a, but we can
                # access a/b *through* a
```

So, `execute permission` or `x` for a *directory* means we can access the path below it, even if we cannot read the contents of the directory itself. In your case, Apache needs permission to *"walk through"* `/mnt/storage/cascornelissen` even though it will not read any files until it reaches `Muziek`.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Would you mind explaining it a little more in-depth? Does apache require execute permissions for every parent of `/Muziek`?

Comment: Will add explanation in answer